# No bluetooth earphone connection for LG FN4 earphones, ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 21.10

I know this is a common problem, hardware is a dell xps 13, read and tried lots of stuff, can not get pulseaudio (sound settings) to recognise earphones for output even though they are paired.  In Blueman-manager they are connected but as a "Miscellaneous" device, could that be it, not recognized as an headphone/earphone/output device?  Any suggestions on how to debug most welcome. Thx. J

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 21.10 with my sony xm2 headphones.

I got it working like this:

I downloaded [the latest bluez package](http://www.bluez.org/download/). I unzipped it and ran the `./configuration` script. This showed me some packages were missing so I installed them

```
sudo apt-get install docutils-common libreadline-dev libical-dev libdbus-1-dev
```

I than made sure to comment out all lines inside `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and then restarted the Bluetooth service:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

After that the headphones became a **Headset** instead of just *Miscellaneous*

---

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me, and this particular device, was to open the charging case, with the earphones still in the case, press the button on the side to start bluetooth pairing.  This did allow pairing, and then I could take them out of the case and use them, and they work, but not well.  The connection often gets dropped.  So it appears the key is to leave the buds in the case until paired.  HTH.